# Xcode Instruments - equivalents for Windows?

Tags: visual-studio, xcode, instruments, dtrace

Xcode's Instruments make me feel physically I'll. They're based on DTrace - which has some loose equivalents in Windows - but the GUI Apple made for them makes them usable in a day to day way.

Visual Studio just doesn't seem to have tools to compete. It has an attempt at a profiler that requires a lot of command line mojo and parsing of text dumps. The Compuware suite of tools are just awful in comparison.

Is there nothing out there with the power and ease of use of Xcode's Instruments - but for windows?

Comment: Weird. I could ask the same question - but exactly the other way round :-)

Comment: how so? You are implying there are profiling tools for windows that are equivalent in quality to Instruments?

Comment: I fell in love with instruments and now that I have to work again on Windows, I miss it lot. So far, I have not come across anything that covers things in such extend. Only bits and pieces that do similar jobs. One example would be [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) when it comes to memory usage of a process.